# how to check if a document exists in firebasefirestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if a doc is exists and I used this doc.exists, but it gives me always false even if the doc exists already

```
Future<bool> isRomeExiste(String userId1, String userId2) async {
    bool exist = false;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('message')
        .doc("JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1-JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1")
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      exist = doc.exists;
    });

    return exist;
  }
```

[image: this is my firebase]

Comment: can you add this inside the `then()`, print(doc.data());

Comment: and check if it prints the document data in the console log

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine `await` and `then`. If you use `await`, it returns the value from the `Future` already.

So:

```
Future<bool> isRomeExiste(String userId1, String userId2) async {
  var doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('message')
      .doc("JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1-JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1")
      .get();

  bool exist = doc.exists;

  return exist;
}
```

---

Note that this will still return false, as there is no document at the path `message/JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1-JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1` in your database. The Firebase console show the path in italics to indicate that there is no document there, but there *are* subcollection.

If you want to be able to check whether the document exists, be sure to create it when you also create the `messages` subcollection. Alternatively, you can check whether the `messages` subcollection has any document with something like:

```
Future<bool> isRomeExiste(String userId1, String userId2) async {
  var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('message/JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1-JryeL6uzGRh86RiY5SXtn58fpup1/messages')
      .limit(1)
      .get();

  bool exist = snapshot.size > 0;

  return exist;
}
```